# What is the best way to check if a Hyperledger Fabric CA server is up and running?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, status, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am setting up a number of Fabric CA servers and am looking for the most reliable way to perform status checks from a centralized server in order to check if they're running or not.

Looking through the documentation, there is no obvious command for doing this.

I'm looking to send a request to the server (from the CA client or node JS) and simply get back whether the server is started or not. Does anyone know of the proper way to do this instead of just pinging the server and checking the response?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fabric CA server is having an operations service that provides REST API for health check and metrics. Operations service can be exposed during `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS` environment variable or using the CA server config file. A sample docker file is provided in [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/41717d76f2cb81e8ebceb023afc5dd4c2260f34f/test-network/compose/compose-ca.yaml#L23). You can curl the /healthz endpoint of the operations service to get the server status.

eg:

```
curl http://localhost:17054/healthz
{"status":"OK","time":"2022-07-18T10:04:18.372186715Z"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fabric CA Servers supports a rest api, so you can query for CA info. For example

```
curl -k https://<CA_URL>/api/v1/cainfo
```

There is also a getcainfo command on fabric-ca-client

these should suffice to check that a CA is up and running